# How to accomplish In-App Purchases in a Xamarin.Forms App?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've noticed that there are components for Xamarin.iOS for In-App purchases, but I don't see anything for Android.  And I haven't found anything that seems to target both or Xamarin.Forms.

Am I missing something?  Or are there not Xamarin.Forms components yet to help with In-App Purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin has an in-app purchase component for both [iOS](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inapppurchase) and [Android](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling).  These functions are very platform specific, so it would be difficult to build a unified API that worked with both platforms.

You can use Form's [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to inject the platform specific behavior of the component into your app.

Comment: Do you have the sample code or tutorial of creating the full Dependency Service ?

Comment: the link above includes samples and walkthroughs